# Hibernate Validator path returns null for `NodeImpl.getValue()` for a custom constraint

Tags: java, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I have the following:

```
@ValidAccount
class Account {
   List<User> users;
}

class User {
   String name;
}
```

And my validator has

```
public boolean isValid (final Account account, final ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        // For the sake of simplicy, I am not looping through the array and just fetching the first entry
        User user = account.getUsers().get(0);
        if (user.getName().equals("SOME_DISALLOWED_NAME")) {
            context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
            context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("name is invalid")
                    .addPropertyNode("users")
                    .addPropertyNode("name").inIterable().atIndex(0)
                    .addConstraintViolation();
            return false;
        }

        return true;
}
```

Now I expect to be able to do

```
// Logging path shows users[0].name
Try.of(() -> (NodeImpl) Iterables.getLast(violation.getPropertyPath()))
    .andThen(node -> {
        final User user = (User) node.getParent().getValue();
    });
```

But this casting fails, as `getValue()` returns `null`. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**

Ultimately, my custom validator is intended to do a unique check that there are no two users with the same `name`

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: `getValue` returns null

Comment: Is it possible you didn't register your custom validator?

Comment: @shinjw no because I do `log` inside my custom validator, and I can see it is validating. Plus the `violation.getMessage()` is the message from the custom validator,

Comment: I've dug into this a little just now.  My best guess is that Hibernate Validator just doesn't store the values in the property path when using the `buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate` API.  I think your validator as written is correct.